# QtWebEngine Issue when I run executable format

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've a python Pyside6 gui, it is working when I run the code on Pycharm. But after that I want to convert executable format in my MacOS.
So I installed pyinstaller in file path file_path/var/site-packeges/
Project using 3.8 version of Python with below commands:

```
    pyinstaller --onefile test1.py
65 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.10.1
65 INFO: Python: 3.8.9
68 INFO: Platform: macOS-12.3.1-arm64-arm-64bit
69 INFO: wrote /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/test1.spec
70 INFO: UPX is not available.
71 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting']
204 INFO: checking Analysis
204 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
204 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
205 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
210 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
474 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
607 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
1113 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
1660 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
1708 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
1712 INFO: Analyzing /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/test1.py
1717 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
1972 INFO: Processing module hooks...
1976 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
2092 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtWidgets.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
2199 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtQuickWidgets.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
2336 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtCore.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
2548 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtOpenGL.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
2656 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtGui.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
2785 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtDBus.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
2914 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtNetwork.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3061 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtPrintSupport.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3219 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtWebEngineCore.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3513 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtQuick.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3649 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtWebChannel.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3823 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtPositioning.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
3982 WARNING: QtLibraryInfo(PySide6): could not find translations with base name 'qtlocation'! These translations will not be collected.
3982 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtQml.py' from '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4160 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4162 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4163 INFO: Including run-time hook '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pyside6webengine.py'
4163 INFO: Including run-time hook '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pyside6.py'
4164 INFO: Including run-time hook '/Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_inspect.py'
4179 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
129 WARNING: Cannot find path ./QtPdfQuick.framework/Versions/A/QtPdfQuick (needed by /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Pdf/libpdfquickplugin.dylib)
309 WARNING: Cannot find path ./QtQuick3DSpatialAudio.framework/Versions/A/QtQuick3DSpatialAudio (needed by /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/qml/QtQuick3D/SpatialAudio/libquick3dspatialaudioplugin.dylib)
457 WARNING: Cannot find path ./QtQuick3DHelpersImpl.framework/Versions/A/QtQuick3DHelpersImpl (needed by /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/qml/QtQuick3D/Helpers/impl/libqtquick3dhelpersimplplugin.dylib)
459 WARNING: Cannot find path ./QtQuickEffects.framework/Versions/A/QtQuickEffects (needed by /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/qml/QtQuick/Effects/libeffectsplugin.dylib)
5267 INFO: Looking for eggs
5267 INFO: Using Python library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../Python3
5269 INFO: Warnings written to /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/build/test1/warn-test1.txt
5275 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/build/test1/xref-test1.html
5306 INFO: checking PYZ
5306 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
5306 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/build/test1/PYZ-00.pyz
5398 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/build/test1/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
5400 INFO: EXE target arch: arm64
5400 INFO: Code signing identity: None
5401 INFO: checking PKG
5401 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
5401 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) test1.pkg
8217 WARNING: Cannot find path @executable_path/../../../../Python3 (needed by /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/bin/python)
58605 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) test1.pkg completed successfully.
58629 INFO: Bootloader /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/run
58629 INFO: checking EXE
58629 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
58629 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
58629 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/dist/test1
58630 INFO: Converting EXE to target arch (arm64)
58641 INFO: Removing signature(s) from EXE
58653 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
59076 INFO: Fixing EXE headers for code signing
59079 WARNING: Cannot find path @executable_path/../../../../Python3 (needed by /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/venv/bin/python)
59082 INFO: Re-signing the EXE
59866 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
.
```

After all these things executable file created but when I open the file I get this error:

```
Sandboxing disabled by user.
The following paths were searched for Qt WebEngine resources:
  
  /var/folders/l9/985bkq8n0kq97vpvhp4clxvw0000gn/T/_MEIhWjxll/PySide6/Qt/resources
  /var/folders/l9/985bkq8n0kq97vpvhp4clxvw0000gn/T/_MEIhWjxll/PySide6/Qt
  /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting
  /Users/duygu/.timezone_app
but could not find any.
You may override the default search paths by using QTWEBENGINE_RESOURCES_PATH environment variable.
zsh: abort      /Users/duygu/PycharmProjects/fiver_converting/timezone_app

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

How can I solve this issue ?

My MacOS system using Python 3.9 but I use Python 3.8 for this project.
**EDIT:**
small test code for the analysing the issue, I have same error when I convert this file to executable format

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtGui,QtCore,QtWidgets,QtWebEngineWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
q = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
q.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://www.google.com/'))
q.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that could reproduce your error ?
At least list your imported modules, the problem usually lies in there with `PyInstaller` errors.

Comment: I added can you check?

Comment: Also I added small test code with same issue

Comment: Ok thanks i'm looking into it, I don't have a Mac but I'm trying to reproduce the error on windows and linux, I'll keep you updated.